# Terraform update 1.0.11 to 1.4.0 - Issues with variable type

Tags: terraform, terraform0.12+

The below snippet works when I run terraform version 1.0.11. But the same is not working for 1.4.0 due to the syntax error. I have tried changing the type by  `type = map(string)` `type = map(any)` and it is not working. How to write this block as per terraform version 1.4.0?

```
variable "rules" {
  description = "Map of known security group rules (define as 'name' = ['from port', 'to port', 'protocol', 'description'])"
  type        = "map"

  default = {
    # HTTP
    http-80-tcp   = [80, 80, "tcp", "HTTP"]
    https-443-tcp = [443, 443, "tcp", "HTTPS"]
    ssh-tcp          = [22, 22, "tcp", "SSH"]
    rdp-tcp          = [3389, 3389, "tcp", "RDP TCP"]
    oracle-db-tcp = [1521, 1521, "tcp", "Oracle"]
    all-all        = [0, 0, "-1", "All protocols"]
    
    # This is a fallback rule to pass to lookup() as default, never be used.
    _ = ["", "", ""]
  }
}
```

The error I am seeing is  `This default value is not compatible with the variable's type constraint`. I have tried all ways to write the variable type and it is not working. In short, what would be the variable type for the variable "rules"?

Comment: Have you considered improving the type and its values to be a  `set(object)` or`map(object)`? It would fix this issue and organize the config code.

Comment: That looks like a `map(list(any))` or `map(set(any))` to me. Either that or an `object` with a bunch of separate `list(any)` or `set(any)` or possibly `tuple(number, number, string, string)` properties defined. I suggest reading over the documentation well to understand the different types https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/type-constraints#map

Answer (score 0):

The quoted string `"map"` seems like a legacy type constraint inherited from a much older version of Terraform, which I expect Terraform is understanding the same as `map(any)`, which asks Terraform to automatically infer what element type you intended. That isn't possible in this case because your map elements are not of consistent types.

---

One way to declare a type constraint for this variable would be like this:

```
  type = map(tuple([number, number, string, string]))
```

This tells Terraform that all members of the map should be four-element tuples with the given element types, which seems to match all of your elements in your default value except the one with the key `_`, which currently has the type `tuple([string, string string])` and so I expect that's why Terraform returned an error here. If you write your `_` element's value as `[null, null, null, null]` or `[0, 0, "", ""]` or anything else which matches the above type constraint then it should work.

---

However, it's very unusual to use a tuple for structured data like this in Terraform. The idiomatic way to define this would be as a map of objects so that each value has a clear name associated with it:

```
  type = map(object({
    from_port   = number
    to_port     = number
    protocol    = string
    description = string
  }))
```

Of course if you define it this way then you'll need to change the default value and all of the callers to pass a map of objects instead, so this would be a breaking change to your module. If a breaking change is infeasible then I suggest to use the map of tuple type constraint I showed first above, since at least it's clear about what types the elements are supposed to have even if it doesn't give the elements helpful names.